# Please Help..Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: sql-server-2008, datasource, connection-timeout

I have tried everything.from `;Connection Timeout=600;` to `pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200"` to everything..I have a query in the data source which i need to run and it takes some time.This Timeout is really annoying !

Comment: What happens when you run this query directly in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: it takes time but it gives me a result after like 1 min 20 -1.30 seconds ..

Comment: if your using bulkcopy, it also has a timeout field you can set.

Comment: its not a copy that i am doing..i am trying to fetch a few records !

Comment: So have you solved this problem?  Please update so we can document the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the select command's timeout value in SqlDataSource's Selecting
event:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
e.Command.CommandTimeout = 30;  //or more time....
}
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to get at with my questions... the default timeout for the datasource select command is 30 seconds.  So set it to a couple of minutes and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ADO.NET?  If so, try using:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
```

Comment: I'm guessing sqdatasource is configured with a short timeout then.  If it's not something you can configure then maybe use ado

Comment: Buddy i need to use the data source..Its imp since i am using nested grid view ..So i need multiple data source !I need the solution ..its killing me! :(